# Does Facebook automatically hide posts?

Tags: facebook

I don't use Facebook more than as a fan of a particular pag.

But I realised that sometimes some posts in my timeline disappear and I don't know how to view those posts. I remember they were there, so I guess Facebook automatically hides posts by the page because I don't think the owner of the page hides them for any reason.

Is that the case? If so, how can I view hidden posts?

Answer (score 1):

Many assumptions here. Your news feed is built based on certain factors, you can change this view by looking for most recent.

For the main view of News Feed, Facebook will select certain pages and friends to appear based on your interactions. Liking and commenting on this page will keep it an active item in your feed.